# Detect when windows display settings are not default

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed an WPF application that docks to the right of the screen. 
But I've noticed that my program malfunctions when the user changes this option to 125 or 150%.

Is there a way in C# to detect what value the user has chosen here?

[image]